# How to print data from this JSON Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the code from json, and i would like to print them out to html page.

```
{"offset":0,
"results":[
  {"link_1/_text":"Reflection",
   "text_1":"January 30, 2015",
   "link_3":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?p=414",
   "link_1":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?cat=67",
   "link_3/_text":"Meditasi: Makna Rasa Sakit",
   "text_list_1":["kebahagiaan","meditasi","Meditasi: Makna Rasa Sakit |Matchmatter.com","on pain kahlil gibran","puisi kahlil gibran"],
   "image_1":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Inspirational-Quotes-Image-Khalil-Gibran.jpg",
   "title_text":"Meditasi: Makna Rasa Sakit",
   "text_2":"Semua manusia yang hidup di dunia ini ingin merasakan kebahagiaan, dalam bentuk apapun."
  },
  {"link_1/_text":"Love and Sex",
   "text_1":"January 26, 2015",
   "link_3":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?p=411",
   "link_1":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?cat=64",
   "link_2":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?cat=65",
   "link_3/_text":"Take and Give",
   "text_list_1":["memberi dan menerima","men","Take and Give","Women"],
   "image_1":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/article-2289562-187F97F8000005DC-947_634x482.jpg",
   "title_text":"Take and Give",
   "text_2":"Untuk beberapa alasan yang sulit dimengerti, alam telah membagi pria dan wanita dalam sebuah perbedaan sikap dalam memandang sebuah hal.",
   "link_2/_text":"Men"
  },
  {"link_1/_text":"Women",
   "text_1":"January 23, 2015",
   "link_3":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?p=404",
   "link_1":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?cat=71",
   "link_3/_text":"10 Saran Bagi Wanita Untuk Menyatakan Cinta Lebih Dulu",
   "text_list_1":["10 saran jika ingin menyatakan cinta","menyatakan cinta",
   "menyatakan cinta kepada pria","menyatakan cinta lebih dulu",
   "Mungkinkah Seorang Wanita Menyatakan Cintanya Lebih Dulu?|Matchmatter.com","wanita"],
   "image_1":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/secret-admirer.jpg",
   "title_text":"10 Saran Bagi Wanita Untuk Menyatakan Cinta Lebih Dulu",
   "text_2":"Apakah anda pernah menyukai seorang pria, dan dilihat dari gelagatnya sepertinya dia juga menyukai anda?"
  }
 ],
  "cookies":[],
  "connectorVersionGuid":"ed0ce142-861e-4d2e-bacd-3dd1de491a69",
  "connectorGuid":"d6d21746-2d8f-4980-b1ec-8e1a5d52b133",
  "pageUrl":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?page_id=709"
 }
```

But the problem is, i got more than one string to call the data, for example

> "link_1/_text":"Reflection"

If i use this code i will got **Just the URL and not title or content**

```
<script>
  var data = '$json_data';
  $(data.results).each(function() { 
    var output = "<p>" + this.link_1 + "</p>";
    $('#placeholder').append(output);
  });
</script>
```

The point is, how to print results of **Reflection**
Can you help me for this code?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your syntax, you can use both jquery or javascript to iterate on the JSON.

```
var data = {---YOUR JSON...};
```

using JQuery

```
$(data.results).each(function () {
    var output = "<div class='container'>";
    output += "<p>" + this.title_text + "</p>";
    output += "<p>" + this.text_1 + "</p>";
    output += "<p>" + this.link_1 + "</p>";
    output += "</div>";
    $('#placeholder1').append(output);
});
```

using Javasscript

```
var d=document.getElementById("placeholder2");
var output="";
for (var i in data.results) {
    output += "<div class='container'>";
    for (var prop in data.results[i]) {
        output += "<p>" + prop + " : " + data.results[i][prop] + "</p>";
    }
    output += "</div>";
}
d.innerHTML=output;
```

[Here the JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3q2p3sgz/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery.parseJSON(). This will give you a js object which you can use to achieve what you want.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
var json = [ 
    { "one": "1" },
    { "two": "2" },
    { "three": "3" }
];

$.each(json, function() {
  $.each(this, function(name, value) {
    /// do stuff
    console.log(name + '=' + value);
  });
});
```